# Angular 9: Using same component for user creation and user editing

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

How can I use a single component for both, edit and create?

The form will be 1:1 the same.

My edit component subscribes to changes of the url id param, and fetches the user item accordingly:

```js
user: User;

constructor(private httpHandler: HttpHandlerService,
          private route: ActivatedRoute) {
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
       this.httpHandler.getUser(userId)
         .subscribe(user => this.user = user);
    });
}
```

This should not occur for the creation (new user). I would like to use an empty User object and not subscribe to anything.

Should I simply check the route params? Or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by checking the :id param to distinguish whether I'm in 'create' or 'update' mode for my component.

```js
      user: User;
      idParam: string;
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
          this.idParam= params[`id`];
          if (!!this.idParam) {
                this.httpHandler.getUser(idParam)
                     .subscribe(user => this.user = user);
            } else {
              this.user = {
                id: '',
                name: ''
              };
          }
        });
      }
```